# Handling arbitrarily large integers in dbase language

Tags: integer, biginteger, xbase

Is there a simple package available that permits programming in xbase ( i.e. dbase or Foxpro syntax) and has a datatype to store and perform simple arithmetical operations on arbitrarily large integers ( say 100,000 decimal digits) ?

Answer (score 0):

YOu are out of luck. THe main problem is that the only way those databases CAN store that is either as a blog or as a large string - and working on the basis of those SUCKS MAJORLY. Not part of what a database is doing. At least the "simple arithmethical operation" is bad bad bad ;) YOu really need that? Outside of some really limited mathematical scenarios float handle that perfectly - x RELEVANT digits are mostly all you need. Unless you try to calculate the exact value of PI on 100.000 digits or something like that.